Import data-tier application (bacpac) into azure SQL edge docker instance
I am trying to import data from a .bacpac sql data file into a azure sql edge container. I have tried 2 ways to achieve it, but unfortunately no luck.

Using sqlpackage cmd tool to import bacpac file into sql instance.


Within a running container of azure sql edge, downloaded and installed sqlpackage-tool for linux.
Copied .bacpac file from host machine to container docker cp host\bpCustomer.bacpac  azuresqledge:/home/mssql/backpack/mydatabase.bacpac
Used command to import db : $ sqlpackage /Action:Import /tsn:localhost /tdn:target_db_name /tu:sa /tp:mypassword /sf:home/mssql/backpack/mydatabase.bacpac

got this error from sql instance:

Error importing database:Could not import package.
Unable to connect to target server 'localhost'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
The settings for connection encryption or server certificate trust may lead to connection failure if the server is not properly configured.


Modified the command to trust target server certificate: $ sqlpackage /Action:Import /tsn:localhost /tdn:target_db_name /tu:sa /tp:mypassword /sf:home/mssql/backpack/mydatabase.bacpac /ttsc:true


Error importing database:Could not import package.
Warning SQL74501: The source contains users that rely on an external authentication provider that is not supported by the target. These users will be treated as users without logins.
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 12824, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to alter a contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.


Tried to run following queries for running sql instance: sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1; GO   RECONFIGURE;   GO
but got this error, saying azure sql edge does not support contained database authentication feature


The specified option 'contained database authentication' is not supported by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.


Providing a .bak file of db.


Copied the .bak file into container at var/opt/mssql/backup
Used following sql queries to restore db.

Restore FilelistOnly from disk = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/mydatabase.bak'

Restore Database mydatabase
From disk = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/mydatabase.bak'
WITH MOVE 'mydatabase_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydatabase_Primary.mdf',
MOVE 'mydatabase_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydatabase_Primary.ldf';


got this error again, about setting contained database authentication = 1 : The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to restore a contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.

TLDR; Need help on how to restore sql .bacpac file into azure sql edge docker container.

The problem is the source database, it is a contained database; Azure SQL Edge, as it has told you, does not support contained databases. You'll need to ensure that the database is not set to be a contained database.

Presumably the database did not come from an Azure SQL Edge environment, so why not use a full version of SQL Server, rather than Azure SQL Edge?

Sure, I can try with full SQL server version rather than azure SQL edge instance, but then we will end up with other non-required features (heavy build) and will not be able to replicate close to client machine environment.

The ".bacpac" file I was using is only compatible to use on database engines that support the "contained database" feature, as mentioned by @Thom A in a comment above. The azure SQL edge does not support this feature to import a contained database ".bacpac". Unsupported features Azure SQL edge
However, we have used the "Generate SQL script" option to get schema and data into a SQL script.
